# General test of the org?

Tags: unit-test, code-coverage

Is there a way to do an organization-wide test? My internship supervisor told me the following: "What I'm going to ask you to do is run a general test of the ORG and see what the percentage of coverage is. Then identify which classes failed for us to perform."

But I only know about the tests in the classes, I'm researching this general test but I still haven't found anything enlightening.
If anyone can help me I would appreciate it

Comment: FYI, here's the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_cli_reference.meta/sfdx_cli_reference/cli_reference_force_apex.htm#cli_reference_force_apex_test_run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using sfdx, use the following command:

```
sfdx force:apex:test:run -l RunLocalTests -r human -c -w 100
```

This will run all tests and report code coverage as well any test failures.